# RHEL 8.3 autofs not mounting NFS directories

Tags: linux, nfs, autofs

RHEL 8.3 64-bit

autofs.x86_64 1:5.1.4-43.el8

I'm trying to enable `autofs` for my system. I've followed the tutorials and, while they make sense, the network drives are not mounting and in some cases present some weird behavior. First, the configuration files

/etc/auto.master.d/mount.nfs:

```
/home/me/  /etc/auto.me.nfs
```

/etc/auto.me.nfs:

```
nas -fstype=nfs4 nas:/data/directory
```

Now when I run:

```
service autofs start
```

It should mount `nas:/data/directory` -> `/home/me/nas`, right? One of two things will happen:

1. Nothing. The directory `/home/me/nas` contains all local contents and `df -h` shows nothing mounted to that location.
2. My home directory will ONLY contain `nas`. It shows in df -h and the remote files are accessible. However, everything else is gone.  An `ls -l` on `/home/` shows my home directory owned by `root.root`

The command:

```
mount nas:/data/directory /home/me/nas
```

Works just fine, inheriting the ownership and permissions from the NFS directory. What am I missing? Is there a log to see what autofs is trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Classic autofs

Situation 1) is probably caused by your `/etc/auto.master.d/mount.nfs` not being named `/etc/auto.master.d/mount.autofs`: according to `auto.master(5)` man page and comment in the `/etc/auto.master` configuration file, any files in `auto.master.d` must have an `*.autofs` suffix to work.

Your situation 2) is basically working exactly like a classic-style `autofs` is expected to work with your current configuration.

With your current configuration, the `/home/me/` directory becomes an *autofs map mountpoint*: a special virtual directory that senses when someone attempts to access it. If you attempt to list the contents of the autofs mountpoint, it will list the contents of the map as sub-directories (in your case, just the `nas` sub-directory), and when you actually attempt to access those sub-directories, `autofs` will automatically mount them as required NFS share before letting that access happen, and can automatically unmount each share when it is no longer being used.

The *indirect maps* (like your current configuration) are really designed for situations like `/home/` being an autofs map mountpoint: the user home directories would then be individual NFS shares in the indirect map, that can be mounted and unmounted as users log in and out. Since updates to indirect maps take effect immediately, new users can be created and old ones removed without restarting the `autofs` service.

If you want to mount the NFS share without an intervening directory, you could do it by defining a *direct map* in `auto.master.d/`:

```
rm /etc/auto.master.d/mount.nfs
echo "/-  /etc/auto.me.nfs" >/etc/auto.master.d/mount.autofs
```

Then changing the contents of `/etc/auto.me.nfs` to:

```
/home/me/nas    -fstype=nfs4 nas:/data/directory
```

And finally restarting the autofs service:

```
systemctl restart autofs
```

This should exactly replicate the effects of the `mount nas:/data/directory /home/me/nas` command whenever you access `/home/me/nas`, and allow it to be unmounted when there are no processes accessing it. But any changes to the configuration of the direct map will require restarting the autofs service, unlike in the case of the indirect map.

---

### Alternative solution with systemd

However, with `systemd`, there is an alternative way to set up a single auto-mounting directory without even needing a separate `autofs` service. Just write an entry in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
nas:/data/directory   /home/me/nas  nfs nfsvers=4,nofail,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

To activate this entry immediately, you would need two commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload                #triggers systemd-fstab-generator to re-make *.mount and *.automount units
systemctl start home-me-nas.automount   #starts the newly created automount unit
```

Otherwise, it would activate automatically at next reboot.

For more details and configuration options, read `man systemd.mount`.